# Monotone Convergence Theorem - clarification on measurable set.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification, lebesgue-measure, proof-explanation

The same question was posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1085203/on-why-a-set-is-measurable-a-step-of-the-proof-of-the-lebesgue-monotone-conver) - but I am unsure why the difference is a measurable function. To summarize:

> Let $f_n: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup \{+\infty\}$ be increasing functions on measure space $(X, \mathbf{X}, \mu)$ that converges to $f$. 
>   Let $\phi:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a simple measurable function satisfying $0 \le \phi \le f$. Let $\alpha \in (0,1)$ and define
>   $$ A_n = \{x \in X: f_n(x) \ge \alpha \phi(x) \} .$$
>   Then $A_n$ is a measurable set for all $n$.

**My proof would go something like this:**

> $$ A_n = \{ x \in X : f_n(x) - \alpha \phi(x) \ge 0 \} $$  $$ =
>  \bigcup _{q \in \mathbb{Q}} \{ x \in X : f_{n}(x) \ge q \} \cap \{
>  \phi (x) \ge q/\alpha \} $$
>
> As both $f_n(x)$ and $\phi(x)$ are measurable functions,  $\{ x \in X : f_{n}(x) \ge q \} \cap \{ \phi (x) \ge q/\alpha \}
>  $ is the intersection of two measurable sets, so is also a measurable
>   set. Lastly, the countable union is also a measurable set.

Is this proof correct? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The argument I had in mind was the following.

Sums and products of measurable functions are measurable; see Proposition 2.6 of *Real Anaylsis* by Folland for example. Therefore, as $f_n$ and $\phi$ are measurable, so is $f_n - \alpha\phi$. Now $A_n = (f_n-\alpha\phi)^{-1}([0, \infty))$ is measurable as $[0, \infty)$ is Borel.

Your proof doesn't work because if $f(x) \geq q$ and $\phi(x) \geq q/\alpha$, then $f(x) - \alpha\phi(x)$ need not be non-negative. If you replace $\phi(x) \geq q/\alpha$ by $\phi(x) \leq q/\alpha$, you certainly obtain a set which is contained in $A_n$, but you would need an argument to justify why it is equal to $A_n$ (it is not clear to me whether it is).